# Código de Javascript se muestra como texto renderizado en la página de inicio

Tags: bug, estado-completado

El código `docsHero.RenderPartial(Html); storyHero.RenderPartial(Html);` se muestra en la parte superior izquierda sobre el texto de 'Preguntas principales'. Esto ocurre autenticado con mi usuario. También reporto que ocurre en la página Meta.

Uso Chromium 56.0.2924.76

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Parece ser que ya fue resuelto, hace una aproximadamente lo vi, pero ahora veo que la página ya está bien :D había puesto el comentario en el [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36550031#36550031)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

De acuerdo a los comentarios de [Michael Stum ♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/91/michael-stum) en [el mismo reporte de bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/293434/304899) en MSE:

> Fue un error al copiar y pegar, mientras estaba refactorizando una lógica de vistas viejas, la cual sólo aparece algunas veces :/ Enviando un push con la corrección. [[comentario original]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/293434/possible-scripting-error-on-all-main-se-front-pages#comment953837_293434)

> Hice una reversión al build anterior, y revisé la vista 2, 3, y hasta 4 veces. Todavía estoy viendo qué sucedió pero, básicamente, es un banner que no se muestra siempre, por eso no lo vi, y no se le muestra a todos. ¡Perdón! [[comentario original]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/293434/possible-scripting-error-on-all-main-se-front-pages#comment953840_293434)

> Solucionado correctamente ahora e hice un roll out del build otra vez. [Hero está funcionando bien de nuevo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=37Tl17aDZC4). [[comentario original]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/293434/possible-scripting-error-on-all-main-se-front-pages#comment953841_293434)

¡Así que ya está solucionado!